Calculate ratio of 2 polygons using QGIS modeler
Working with QGIS modeler, I need to do some arithmetic operations with some polygon areas.
Let's say there are 2 polygons in layer A and layer B. And I'm inputting them into the model using Vector Layer input. And I need to calculate the ratio of area of these 2 polygons. Then I'll use that number in another algorithm.

This is what I thought I could do, but apparently it's not working.

Can anyone help me get around this problem?

Expression:
aggregate( layer:=@poly_a, aggregate:='sum', expression:=$area) / aggregate( layer:=@poly_b, aggregate:='sum', expression:=$area)
Aggregate will sum all polygon areas of each input layer.
I use the output to calculate a column in layer B, just to verify that Calculate Expression is working.


Yeah, I managed to run it without the Field Calculator. My mistake was thinking there's only 1 polygon in an input layer. Using aggregate makes sense and works. But is there another way with single polygon per layer assumption?
